# Azure non-production deployment slot will redirect to production slot after giving development error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app set up in Azure. It is a C# ASP.NET 6.0 MVC application using an Azure database. The website on the production slot is working correctly and reacts as would be expected. I have set up an additional deployment slot called "master". For it I directed the CI/CD towards the Azure Repos where our source control is kept. I can from Visual Studio 2022 perform a commit and push and it will build and redeploy the "master" site. If I then perform a swap with the production site and the master site, my changes will be reflected on the production site. However; I am not able to visit the master site's URL. It will redirect me to the production URL and give me the following error.

"Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application. Check the server logs for error details and enable logging."

I have tried changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT configuration in Azure to development for the master slot and production for the production slot. I have also tried changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in my lanuchSettings.json file to development as well.

I have tried adjusting the traffic as well around trying to force a redirect to the master site.

I've hit a wall with this one and have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps your CICD itself is resetting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable?

Comment: @RosdiKasim I have the deployment slot checkbox checked. So I believe that that environment variable should stay with the master slot. I have also tried deselecting it as well to no avail. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was the authentication that was being used on the site. The site uses the Azure B2C and the master site was not registered with B2C causing it to reroute to the production site. All that needed to be done was to take the URI and add it to the list on Azure B2C. Thanks,